# Android : Proguard is not working in debug mode

Tags: android

Proguard is working well for release version but it is not work for debug version.

Here is my build.gradle file

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        lintOptions {
            disable 'MissingTranslation'
        }
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        lintOptions {
            disable 'MissingTranslation'
        }
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
```

Comment: what you mean by not working?

Comment: when apk run in debug mode, class file doesn't change.

Comment: post the error in question